# using jquery to load json

Tags: jquery, json

I have a variable on a page like this:

> var userdetails = "{ 'id': '1',
>   'username': 'me', }";

now, I wanna call a function to load those id and username in some divs
like this one:

> loaduser(userdetails)

I used this but didn't work

> function loaduser(jsoni){
>
> $.getJSON(jsoni, function(data) {
>         $('#id').html(data.id);
>         $('#username').html(data.username);
>     }
>   }

thank u guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). Your example won't work though because it is not valid JSON (valid JSON requires double instead of single quotation marks):

```
var userdetails = '{ "id": 1, "username": "me", }';
```